# how can I avoid Package sebastian/resource-operations is abandoned, error while creating a new laravel application

Tags: laravel

I opened `powershell` and I run `laravel new pp` command to create a new application but I am unable to do so and this error occurs:

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest [Laravel installer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#the-laravel-installer) installed, so see the documentation and install it again running `composer global require laravel/installer` as the documentation shows.

---

#### Edit

That is only a warning, it should not stop your Laravel build, and there is really nothing you can do about it (to hide it at least) as it is related to [`phpunit/phpunit`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/a9e13cd2af1e5512c3b3dc23fa777a8a23370585/composer.json#L49), but it is just a warning.

Read [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4714) and you will see why it was abandoned and that it will be fixed when phpunit 10 is released (if you upgrade to it).